# Getting position of a string in a file in unix

Tags: shell, unix

Suppose I have a file which contains 10 lines. each line contains unique word e.g. "Mark"
Position of "Mark" is different in all the 10 lines.
I want to know how to get, in 1st line position of the "Mark". Similar goes with all the lines.
I tried with grep -H 'Mark', but it's not giving me what I want.
any way to calculate the same??

**Filname** : abc.txt

```
Hi Mark, how are you?
Mark is a software engineer.
Stackoverflow is such a great portal.
Annual salary of Mark is $50000, but not upto the mark.
```

Comment: You should show expected output also. I am getting `4 1 0 18` on different lines for this file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this awk to print first position of a keyword in each line:

```
awk -v s='Mark' '{print index($0, s)}' file
```

Comment: 0
0
0
0
4
0
52
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
5
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
11
0
0
0
0
0
0
44
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
not expected result anubhava :(

Comment: I want to get result like in 1st line position of "Mark" 3 etc.

Comment: Provide a sample file data in your question with expected output. It is not possible to understand from comment.

Comment: Filename : abc.txt
Hi Mark, How are you.
Mark is a software engineer.

Comment: As I suggested earlier you need to click on edit link of your question and provide this data otherwise in comments formatting gets lost. I can't make out if this is one line or multiple lines. You must also provide your expected output in question.